# How do I stop Windows 10 from resetting my default browser?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, file-association, microsoft-edge, firefox-developer-edition

Windows 10 keeps resetting my default browser to Microsoft Edge. I am trying to run Firefox Developer Edition as my default browser. The reset happens randomly, maybe once every week or two, but it is rather annoying.

I talked to Microsoft support and they wanted me to turn off Windows Update (!). I declined. I suspect it may be related, though.

My Windows Update history shows that the last update was KB3213986, applied on 2017-01-12. I noticed that my browser had been reset on 2017-01-16.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Is there a fix?

Comment: This only happens with a feature update, it doesn't happen with normal security updates, and it's behavior that can't be avoided (just how the feature updates work)

Comment: Try setting it through Settings, System, Default Apps, and make sure you also set it to Edge and then away from it to Firefox. Had a similar problem once and that fixed it.

Comment: Are you using a vanilla release, or are you on one of the Insider Preview rings?

Answer (score 2):

The default browser is set in the Registry under

> HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\http

and

> HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\https

[image: User-set default browser]

These user settings take precedent over those in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, which may be ignored.

You could right-click on the *command* key and change permissions so it is less likely that Windows will mangle your settings on the next update.

You can also make a small .reg file, exporting those settings, so the next time MS *does* foul it up, you just need to merge it back into the Registry.